# Using VBA to apply different conditional formatting to a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to get a feel for how to proceed. I am having end users provide me with information that needs to be validated across several columns in excel.

Since the incoming data is likely to be copied and pasted from source spreadsheets, using data validation is going to be difficult.

In order to keep the validations straight I have mirrored my data layout in a sheet called "Rules" and entered in the formulas that I would like to use for the columns.

For example: In cell A2 I have the following :
=NOT(AND(LEN(A2)<51,=IF(A2<>"",SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2),Validations!$A$2:$A$41,"")))=LEN(A2))))
Which would be the data validation that would continue for all cells in column A excluding A1.

Cell B2 Would have a corresponding formula in it, and so on and so forth until column BY.

I the following code is a rough estimate on what is happening for a sigle column, without grabbing the conditional formula from a cell value:

```
Sheets("TestInput").Select
    With Range("A2:A60000")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=IF(A2<>"""",NOT(AND(LEN(A2)<51,SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2),Validations!$A$2:$A$41,"""")))=LEN(A2))))"
        With .FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = False
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
```

My Ideal end point is getting this to work where the conditional formatting rules/formula for A2-A60000 is loacted in Sheet "Rules" Cell "A2" and the formatting rules/formula for B2-B60000 is located in Sheet "Rules" Cell "B2" & so on and so forth up until Column BY.

Thanks in advance for taking a peek!

Tim

Comment: The idea behind this being, Once all data is copied and pasted onto the sheet, I can run a macro to reapply the conditional formatting to the cells that now have new data in them and highlight anything outside of acceptable conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. You have done already 90% of the process. Just define your formulas in the cell A2 and B2 without = or anything else (see example).

[image: Formula example]

Here is your improved code:

```
Sub repaint()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsRules As Worksheet

    'Disable updates/events
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Define here your worksheets
    Set ws = Table1
    Set wsRules = Table2

    'Clear and reset format conditions in column A
    With Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(60000, 1))
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & wsRules.Cells(2, 1).Text
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            'TODO format your stuff
        End With
    End With

    'Clear and reset format conditions in column B
    With Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(60000, 2))
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & wsRules.Cells(2, 2).Text
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            'TODO format your stuff
        End With
    End With

    'Enable updates/events
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This got me exactly where I needed to go. Thinking about nesting these in a For Variablename 1 to 78 etc!